# Easy question regarding quadratic equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Note: This is part of my preparations for my exams, im getting the wrong answer as $32/17$ which is not what wolfram alpha says, i would highly appreciate it if somebody could provide a direct answer so i can see what went wrong.

The equation here is $\frac{x+3}{x-2} - \frac{1-x}{x} = \frac{17}{x}$

Note: brackets are there to seperate, they dont haveany special meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply through so that all values have the same denominator:

$\frac{x^2+3x}{x^2-2x} - \frac{-x^2+3x-2}{x^2-2x} = \frac{17x-34}{x^2-2x}$

Then simplify:

$\frac{2x^2+2}{x^2-2x} = \frac{17x-34}{x^2-2x}$

$2x^2+2 = 17x-34$

$2x^2-17x+36 = 0$

**Edit:** So, to continue, since you seem to have gotten to this point, you come up with factors:

$(2x-9)(x-4) = 0$

So the roots are $4$ and $4\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: i already did that

Comment: See my edits. I completed the equation.

Comment: Thanks, i finally understand.